# Is it possible to have presets for digitizing in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, digitizing

I want to digitize many identical features (same attributes). They will have different location. Type: points and lines.
Is it possible to have presets? Like to select: "traffic calming" and then all the attributes of those presets apply, without me having to manually state which attributes that feature has.

Comment: From the menubar, you could use `View > Select > Select by expression` and enter an expression like `"Field_Name" = 'traffic calming'` to select all features in a layer which has this attribute.

Comment: @Joseph that would allow the attributes to be set after features are created- this question is asking for an ability similar to ArcGIS Feature Templates where you get a 'palette' of pre-defined features you can draw with...

Comment: @DPSSpatial - Thanks for clarifying =). There was the [featuretemplates](https://github.com/NathanW2/featuretemplates) tool which was being developed but not sure how far that got. Otherwise you could try the [AutoFields](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/AutoFields/) plugin.

Comment: @Joseph Oh nice those would both be useful plugins, actually - in addition to the 'feature template', the arcgis 'subtype and domain' concepts allow the ability to auto-assign attributes to new features, which is valuable for digitizing workflows...

Comment: @DPSSpatial - Interesting, I hear ArcGIS does have a 'few' extra tools than QGIS ;)

Comment: @Joseph replace 'few' with 'many' and 'tools' with 'distractions' and you'd be getting close...

Answer (score 4):

No - not as of version 2.16. It's something that myself and a few of the other core developers would love to add but would need someone to step up and sponsor this work.

In versions >= 2.18 you can however set default values for fields, so that could potentially get you part-way there.

Answer (score 4):

While waiting for this amazing new functionality, you can use the Autofields plugin, which can fill expression-based information into your fields at creation.

You can also just set the option in QGIS to use the last used value when creating new features:

[image: use last values]